# SiriTipView doesn't localise commands

Tags: swift, swiftui, localization, appintents

I have my commands saved in Ropes/AppShortcuts.strings and they appear well in shortcuts app but in SiriTipView It stays like this(photo bellow):

[image: SiriTipView appear]

My code:

```
SiriTipView(intent: AddRopeShortcut())
                    .frame(width: 100)
```

Localization:

`"Create a ${applicationName}" = "Создать ${applicationName}";`

command:

```
"Create a \(.applicationName)"
```

I tried to move AppShortcuts.strings directly in my project folder
P.S. iOS 16.3 beta 2 and Xcode 14.2, macOS 13.2 beta 2

Comment: I have an issue where my application name is not translated. Have you filed an Apple bug?

Comment: I can confirm the bug is still there for iOS16.
On iOS17, the bug is fixed, yet I believe most users still use iOS16... 

Comment: On iOS 17, even the SiriTipView is not localized for me, always "Say...", my Siri is not in English.